# What is the grammatical term for "only"?

Tags: terminology

In this line "I said to my agent I only want to work with even bigger stars" (from the Graham Norton Show https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kw_o8LYX5dw), what is the language term for the word "only"?

Comment: It’s a focusing modifier, here an adverb. Surely we must have duplicates about this?

Comment: _Even_ is also a focusing modifier, and it's also an adverb, modifying _bigger_. That's a very complex sentence, with two focusing modifiers and a comparative construction; it's not easy to understand.

Comment: "I said to my agent [that] I only want to work with even bigger starts".

Comment: It's quite straightforward. "Only" is an adverb functioning as a focusing modifier. Here it is modifying the verb phrase _want to work with even bigger stars_. You didn't ask, but "even" is not a focusing modifier but a degree adverb modifying "bigger". Incidentally, do not confuse the adverb "only" with the adjective "only" that is found in examples like _My only reservation_.